# routing-controllers res.sendFile() notfound error

Tags: express, routing-controllers

I was try to download files from server using client.I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/routing-controllers for routings but unable to download file.

**Code**

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { Body, Controller, Get, JsonController, Param, Post, Req, Res } from "routing-controllers";
import { Response } from "express";

@JsonController('/tpm-report')
export class TPMReportController{

@Get('/dowloadfile')
downloadfile( @Res() response: Response)
{
 return response.sendFile('eList.pdf',{root:'sftp-files/'});
    
}

}
```

I didn't know what's my mistakes it's throw NotFound error but the file is available in the mentioned path.

**Error Message**

> Error:
> at NotFoundError.HttpError [as constructor] (D:\WorkSpace-PerumalSamy\abc-WEB\src\http-error\HttpError.ts:19:22)
> at new NotFoundError (D:\WorkSpace-PerumalSamy\abc-WEB\src\http-error\NotFoundError.ts:10:9)
> at ExpressDriver.handleSuccess (D:\WorkSpace-PerumalSamy\abc-WEB\src\driver\express\ExpressDriver.ts:332:23)
> at D:\WorkSpace-PerumalSamy\abc-WEB\src\RoutingControllers.ts:160:45
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Comment: Does `routing-controller` has any method as `sendFile`?

Comment: No **routing-controller** extends **express** methods. but i'm not sure.do you know download files using routing-controller please help me.